# MySQL PHP Graph

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table as shown below:

[image: MySQL Table]

In PHP I want to create a graph using this MySQL table data, graph should be like below:

[image: Expected Graph]

Where Blue lines will refer number of tickets CaughtBy Monitoring and Redlines will refer number of tickets Caughtby Support.

Can someone guide me with the code using any opensource Graph package in PHP.

Comment: Best is not to make this in PHP, but to use Javascript. Send the data in JSON format to the js framework, and the framework will do the rest. You could for example use [chartJs](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html). If you want to use PHP per se (e.g. you need a image) you could use this [example](http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_bar1.php)

Comment: Can you please guide me with code, I am not much into PHP and javascript

Answer (score 0):

You will have to send the table data to JS using AJAX request. 
Then using something like Chart.js, you can implement the chart on the page.
Hope this helps.